# Host Key verification failed: When connecting from Elasticbeanstalk to another AWS instance

Tags: linux

I cannot ssh from my AWS instance to another AWS instance. It shows Host Key Verification failed. I tried adding the instance’s public IP address to Known_hosts as well but it doesn’t make any difference.

I am using the following command to login:
ssh -i Id_rsa.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-yy-zz.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

**Output:**
web: Host key verification failed

I am expecting to login to the Instance and executing my shell script over there